# C# Unity Create Mesh From Array of 2D Verticies

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

So I've been working on a little project in c# & Unity, most recently I constructed an algorithm to validate (i.e. Ensure no unexpected overlapping of line segments on) a 2D Shape. Now I would like to procedurally generate triangles properly connecting the vertices on this new 2D shape to each other. My problem is that, while the shape is solid, I do not know how to test if a triangle created by connecting three points lies within the shape and isn't mistakenly creating geometry outside the shape. I'm not looking for a huge algorithm to do everything, just maybe some math tips and whatnot on testing if a triangle lies on a complex plane segment.

Comment: this question is better asked at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com or http://answers.unity3d.com

Comment: I had a similar problem and used the Clipper library to help#

Comment: One algorithm for this problem is ear cutting or ear clipping.